# Elastic search: how to 'OR' two different nested queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I have a `User` mapping like:

```
name: { 
 type: "string"
},
followed_groups: {
  type: "nested",
  properties: {
    created_at: {
      type: "string"
    },
    group_id: {
      type: "string"
    }
  }
},
id: {
  type: "integer"
},
member_of_groups: {
  type: "nested",
  properties: {
    created_at: {
      type: "string"
    },
    group_id: {
      type: "string"
    }
  }
}
```

And I'd like to get users who are either following a group or a member of it.

Each individual query is ok using nested query like:

```
"query":{
  "nested":{
    "query":{
      "terms":{
        "followed_groups.group_id":[
          "22"
        ]
      }
    },
    "path":"followed_groups"
  }
}
```

But I cannot find a way to combine the two with a `OR` condition. Is it possible please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you do not care about the scoring provided by using queries, see below for a solution using filters.

One can simply use the query directive you have given inside the array of queries in the should directive:

```
{ "query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "query" : {
          "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "terms" : {
                "followed_groups.group_id" : [
                  "22"
                ]
              }
            },
            "path" : "followed_groups"
          }
        }
      },
      {…}
    ]
  }
}}
```

---

It is possible to use filters at the top level, but this doesn't fare well when also using faceting, so I'll be using a [filtered](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query.html) query here:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
        "filter" :{   "or" : [
          {
            "nested":{
               "query":{
                 "terms":{
                   "followed_groups.group_id":[
                     "22"
                   ]
                 }
               },
               "path":"followed_groups"
             }
           },
           {…}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I haven't tested this, but this should at least give the right structure for your query.

Comment: why is this line useful please? `"query" : { "match_all" : {} },`

Comment: in your filtered section, I should `OR` two filters, so the current syntax is not ok

Comment: The match_all query is used just have a query that matches anything, it is the cheapest query there is. This is needed because the query directive is required. When using a top level filter this would not be necessary.

Comment: On recent ES versions, the query part in `filtered` query shouldn't be required.